# How to render all object properties from array of objects

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have an array called `courses[]`, in this array there are multiple objects. Each object represents a single course.

I'm trying to render out all my object properties for each course. With my current way of doing this I can `console.log` all my object properties but I'm unsure how I would render it out to the DOM. I tried the following but doesn't render out anything:

```
<div className="courses">
    {
      courses.map(course =>
        Object.keys(course).forEach((val, key) => {
          return <div key={key}>{val}</div>;
        })
      )
    }
</div>
```

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A `forEach` does not return anything. Instead use `map` and it should work.

e.g.

```
Object.keys(course).map(...)
```